# C++ question: Objects of abstract class type "manager" are not allowed

Tags: c++

I have build up a project to review C++. My project has 5 files totally: main.c, technician.h, technician.c, employee.h, employee.c

employee.h

```
#pragma once
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class employee
{
public:
    employee();
    virtual ~employee();

    //worker's salary
    virtual void getpay() = 0;
    //worker's information
    virtual void displaystatus() = 0;
    //way to correct worker's level
    virtual void uplevel(int level) = 0;
protected:
    string name;
    int id;
    double salary;
    int level;

    static int startNum;
};
```

employee.cpp

```
#include "employee.h"
#include <iostream>
int employee::startNum = 1000;

employee::employee() {
    cout << "employee()..." << endl;
    id = startNum++;
    level = 1;
    salary = 0.0;
}

employee::~employee(){
    cout << "~employee()..." << endl;
}
```

technician.h

```
#pragma once
#include "employee.h"

class technician :public employee
{
    technician();
    ~technician();

    virtual void getpay();
    virtual void displaystatus();
    virtual void uplevel(int level);
private:
    int workhour;
    double permoney;
};
```

technician.cpp

```
#include "technician.h"
technician::technician() {
    cout << "technician()..." << endl;
    cout << "Please input the worker's name：" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    permoney = 100;
    workhour = 0;
}
technician::~technician() {
    cout << "~technician()..." << endl;
}

void technician::getpay() {
    cout << "Please input the total hours for a worker:" << endl;
    cin >> workhour;
    this->salary = this->permoney * this->workhour;
}
void technician::uplevel(int level) {
    this->level += level;
 }
void technician::displaystatus() {
    cout << "Worker's name:" << this->name << endl;
    cout << "worker's level:" << this->level << endl;
    cout << "worker's salary:" << this->salary << endl;
    cout << "worker's ID:" << this->id << endl;
 }
```

main.cpp

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<iostream>
#include"employee.h"
#include"technician.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    employee *eml = new technician;
  
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know when I compile this project, the compiler tells me that there is something wrong with the main. c, which points that **' new technician'** I want to know which part was wrong in my project.

By the way, I used visual studio.

Another question is that I wrote another class, here are the program files you can see them below:

manager.cpp

```
#include "manager.h"
manager::manager() {
    cout << "manager()..." << endl;
    cout << "Please input the manager's name:" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    this->fixsalary = 8000;
}

manager::~manager() {
    cout << "~manager()..." << endl;
}


void manager::getpay() {
    this->salary = this->fixsalary;
 }
 void manager::uplevel(int level){
     this->level += level;

     if (this->level == 1) {
         this->fixsalary = 8000;
     }
     else if (this->level == 2) {
         this->fixsalary = 15000;
     }

 }
```

manager.h

```
#pragma once
#include "employee.h"

class manager :public employee
{
public:
    manager();
    ~manager();

    virtual void getpay();
    virtual void uplevel(int level);

private:
    double fixsalary; // Manager's stable salary
};
```

Now I add "**employee* eml = new manager;**" in main.c and the compiler told me that ***"manager": cannot instantiate abstract classes***. I don't know what's the matter with it.

Comment: All of the member function of `technician`, including its constructor and destructor, are `private`.   Such classes cannot be constructed by any function that is not declared a `friend`.   Declare the constructors and destructor (as a minimum) to be `public`.

Comment: There is no "manager" mentioned anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to make the constructor (and destructor) of `technician` public. And you probably want the public methods from employee that you override as public too.

Methods in class declarations default to private unless a public/protected label appears earlier in the declaration.

Instead of this:

```
class technician :public employee
{
    technician();
    ~technician();

    virtual void getpay();
    virtual void displaystatus();
    virtual void uplevel(int level);
```

This:

```
class technician :public employee
{
public:
    technician();
    ~technician();

    virtual void getpay();
    virtual void displaystatus();
    virtual void uplevel(int level);
```

It appears you already know this, based on your declaration of `employee`.

While, I'm here, it's better for readability (and compiler can error check better) to explicitly use the newer `override` keyword for virtual functions you  overtake in the inherited class.

```
class technician :public employee
{
public:
    technician();
    ~technician();

    void getpay() override;
    void displaystatus() override;
    void uplevel(int level) override;
```

The advantage of `override` is that it guards against the all too common error of misspelling an overwritten method name in a derived class.

Comment: Oh! I got it! Thanks for your notification! I run the project successfully!

Comment: Good to hear. Don't forget to upvote the answer and/or accept it if you found it useful.

Comment: By the way, I would like to ask you another question. I also wrote another class. Here is the program files:

Comment: `manager` is a derived class, but doesn't override `displaystatus`, which is declared pure virtual in the base class.

Comment: So how to deal with the manager.h or manager.cpp files?

Comment: Add an implementation of `displaystatus` to your manager class.

Comment: Could you please edit your first answer to show me? I'm sorry that I don't know exactly how to add an implementation in manager.cpp file. Thanks so much!

Comment: Just like you have a function on your technician class called `displaystatus`, have a similar method on `manager`.

Comment: In any case, Stack Overflow strictly discourages run-on questions - where the OP keeps extending the original question with more sub-questions after you the initial query was answered.  If you got an additional question, create a completely separate question.

Comment: Oh, I got it! The reason is that I didn't add "virtual void displaystatus() override;" in manager.h and declared in manager.cpp. Even though this function I didn't use in manager class, I must declare this function in both manager.h and manager.cpp. That means the derived class must contain all functions which were defined in the base class. Thank you som much!